# Outputting HDF5 file using Django framework

Tags: python, django

I'm making a website using the Django framework. I've successfully gotten a web app that takes user data, uses that to make a query, and the outputs a CSV file. However, what I'd really like is to output an HDF5 file. I googled around and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on outputting an HD5F file from a Django web app. I tried adapting the Django example of outputting a PDF (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-pdf/) like this,

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/hdf5')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.hdf5"'

h = h5py.File(response)
h.create_dataset('Name', data=test[0].name)
```

but I get an error,

> 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'encode'

So I guess I'm misunderstanding how to use content_type in Django's HttpResponse. Does anybody have any experience with outputting HDF5 files form a Django web app or could help clarify how I might adapt the HttpResponse to work with HDF5?

Thank you.